# How to route to a node server in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, routes

I have a little rails server and a node server that I'm trying to connect. The rails server is my main one and I'm trying to figure out how to map a route to the node server.

I want the link to it to be displayed to the user as the normal website url followed by /chat. To that ends I tried something like this:

```
get 'chat', to: redirect('localhost:5000')
```

But that didn't work, giving me a (seemingly?) really random error:

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

I also tried using a redirect straight to the index.html of the node server but as it's not under public, that didn't work, so I'm completely at a loss of how to do this.

Comment: Have you thought of using something like nginx to live in front of the two web servers (rails and node) and send the requests based on the URLs to those two separately?

Comment: Ok, I was afraid it might be some technology I wasn't familiar with yet. I guess this gives me an excuse to go out and learn it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :)